# fastapi create_engine connect_args

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi, sqlmodel

In fastapi, I'm going to pass some postgres connection configs with `create_engine` as follow:

```
engine = create_engine(
    settings.DATABASE_URL,
    echo=False,
    max_overflow=300,
    pool_size=50,
    connect_args={
        "options": "-c statement_timeout=5000 -c idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=1000000 "
        "-c idle_session_timeout=1000000"
    },
)
session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine)
def db_session():
    try:
        database = session()
        yield database
    finally:
        database.close()
    return database


# Then in the controller layer:
@router.get("/", response_model=list[models_schema.Model])
def get_all_models(
    session: Session = Depends(db_session),
):
    return get_all_x_models(db=session)
```

I read [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html) that `statement_timeout`, `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` and `idle_session_timeout` are in milliseconds. But on my stage environment when I set `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` and `idle_session_timeout` to 100_000 (100 seconds) I sometimes get this error:

> terminating connection due to idle-session timeout

So I had to set these values so big so that I don't face this issue.
Why this happens? And what should I set?

Thank you very much for your time and consideration.

Comment: Do you have any long-running transactions in your app? If not, this is probably a problem with how you are managing your sessions.

Comment: No I don't, there are just some real-time APIs. Yes I think that might be related. I edited my question and I mentioned my sessions code also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely disable `idle_session_timeout`.

> A value of zero (the default) disables the timeout. Unlike the case with an open transaction, an idle session without a transaction imposes no large costs on the server

```py
engine = create_engine(
    settings.DATABASE_URL,
    echo=False,
    max_overflow=300,
    pool_size=50,
    connect_args={
        "options": "-c statement_timeout=5000 -c idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=1000000 "
        "-c idle_session_timeout=0"
    },
)
```

[PostgreSQL Documentation](https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/idle_session_timeout/#:%7E:text=A%20value%20of%20zero%20)